# Extract and compare column data by date in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, calculated-columns, lubridate

I am using a Kaggle data set for bike sharing. I would like to write script that compares my predicted values to the training data set. I would like comparisons of the mean by month for each year.

The training data set, I call df looks like this:

```
              datetime count
1 2011-01-01 00:00:00    16
2 2011-01-11 01:00:00    40
3 2011-02-01 02:00:00    32
4 2011-02-11 03:00:00    13
5 2011-03-21 04:00:00     1
6 2011-03-11 05:00:00     1
```

My predicted values, I call sub look like this:

```
             datetime count
1 2011-01-01 00:00:00    42
2 2011-01-11 01:00:00    33
3 2011-02-01 02:00:00    33
4 2011-02-11 05:00:00    36
5 2011-03-21 06:00:00    57
6 2011-03-11 07:00:00   129
```

I have isolated the month and year using the lubridate package. Then concatenated the month-date as a new column. I used the new column and split, then use lapply to find the mean.

```
library(lubridate)
df$monyear <- interaction(
    month(ymd_hms(df$datetime)),
    year(ymd_hms(df$datetime)),
    sep="-")
s<-split(df,df$monyear)
x <-lapply(s,function(x) colMeans(x[,c("count", "count")],na.rm=TRUE))
```

But this gives me the average for each month-year combination nested in a list so it is not easy to compare. What I would like instead is :

```
  year-month train-mean sub-mean diff
1 2011-01    28         37.5      9.5
2 2011-02    22.5       34.5      12
3 2011-03    1          93        92
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. You want to join by moth/year, but you provided hourly data sets for the same date. Anyway, All you need here is a simple merge as I see it. You can do both operations simultaneously using `data.table`s binary join combined with `by = .EACHI`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have modified the question so that it is reproducible. Is it possible for you to expand on your answer?

Comment: See my answer. Though keep in mind that `37.5-28 != 15.5`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. For each of your data sets:

```
library(dplyr)
dftrain %>% group_by(monyear) %>% summarize(mc=mean(count)) -> xtrain
dftest %>% group_by(monyear) %>% summarize(mc=mean(count)) -> xtest
merged <- merge(xtrain, xtest, by="monyear")
```

Comment: What's `monyear`? Where's the means difference step? Did you even try this code?

Comment: You are quite right, I did not. `monyear` is specified in the question as an element of `df`. The poster did not tell me what the names of his test and training data set are, so I gave them intuitive names. I also assumed that the poster would be able to deduct one column from another. Good morning!